# How to test (automatedly) that an operation occurs after browser repaint?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, browser

According to [the comments of this blog post](http://www.nonblocking.io/2011/06/windownexttick.html), the following technique executes an operation asynchronously but waits for a repaint:

```
function nextTick(callback) {
    var img = new Image;
    img.onerror = callback;
    img.src = 'data:image/png,' + Math.random();
}
```

whereas this one does not wait for a repaint:

```
var mc = new MessageChannel;
function nextTick(callback) {
    mc.port1.onmessage = callback;
    mc.port2.postMessage(0);
}
```

How could I verify this, programmatically, in a way that automated tests running on multiple platforms/browsers could check?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of the workaround in the blog post.

Read more about it at Paul Irish's blog http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Not interested in animation at all. Looking to do computation yet yield to the browser to make the UI responsive while I do so. (According to the linked comments, the former yields to the browser UI while the latter yields to other JavaScript code.)